# Hello. I am having a problem to change the pages in my django project that it shows a page not found (404)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I've been building my first Django project, and I was doing the "login page", and it is working, but when then, I've made a condition that if the login is wrong, it comes back to the login page and shows an error message, and if it is right, it should go to a page where is written "logadissimo", but when I try this last one, I get the problem below:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://localhost:8000/ Using the URLconf defined in sitetcc.urls,
>   Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ login/ login/submit login/logado The empty path didn't match
>   any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
>   settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

this is my url.py from the project:

```py
"""
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls.conf import include
from django.urls import path
from core import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.login_user),
    path('login/submit', views.submit_login),
    path('login/logado', views.logado)
]
```

the urls.py from the application:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login_user, name='login'),
     path('', views.submit_login, name='submit'),
      path('', views.logado, name='logado')
]
```

the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.

def logado(request):
    return render(request, 'logado.html')

def login_user(request):
    return render(request,'login.html')

@csrf_protect
def submit_login(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print(username)
        print(password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/logado/')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Usuário e senha inválido. Favor tentar novamente:')
    return redirect('/login/')
```

and a print screen with the folders' structure and the page "logado":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w49Ks.jpg

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try `return redirect('logado')` and  `return redirect('login')` syntax `return redirect('your_view_name')`

Comment: Since you're using the `@csrf_protect` decorator, you need to add the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag inside your `<form>` in your html, like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-template)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're passing a hardcoded URL (`/logado/`) to `redirect` that doesn't exists in your project's `url.py`, so Django can't match that route.

There are a couple of ways you can pass an argument to `redirect`, you can see some examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples). I strongly recommend you to use the `name` of your url's view, so in the future you can change the route of your path without any issues.

Also, you can declare your URLs like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs), in that way you'll keep things clean and not bloat your project's `urls.py`.

Doing this you'll have your project's `urls.py` like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls.conf import include
from django.urls import path
from core import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', include('core.urls'),
]
```

And your application's `urls.py` like this:

```py
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login_user, name='login'),
     path('login/submit/', views.submit_login, name='submit'),
      path('login/logado/', views.logado, name='logado')
]
```

(Don't forget the trailing `/` at the end of each route)

Now you can call your view like this `return redirect('core:logado')`